# WP7: Access built in events

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm want to know how can I create an application that is launched with built in events in windows phone like incoming call or email reception.

Comment: Simple answer: you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things that you can add your app to. Perhaps you create a Photo App or a Music App. You can register your app as that type and it will prompt the user to open a photo or song with your app.

[Developing Windows Phone 8 apps with file and URI associations](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXtyeo4K3FU&feature=youtu.be)

Outside of that though you cannot access phone events. Functions such as this are locked off to developers by Microsoft to provide added security to users and also provide a consistent experience across the platform.